# Auto Extract Interface in AX2012 X++ Code Editor

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, morph-x

Is there a function in X++ editor that lets you auto-extract an interface after implementation?

Likewise there is such a function in Visual Studio that is auto-extracting an implemented interface by providing method stubs for all the methods needed for implementing the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such feature.

But you can write one. See sample code below.
And add `Action menu item` to `\Menus\SysContextMenu`.

Alternatively you can add method to [`\Classes\EditorScripts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa676080.aspx)

```cs
public static void main(Args _args)
{
    #macrolib.AOT

    SysContextMenuAOT menuAot;
    TreeNode tn;
    DictClass dc;
    DictMethod dm;
    int i, j;
    str dmName;
    str intSrc, intParams;

    TreeNode itnRoot, itnChild;

    if (!SysContextMenu::startedFrom(_args))
    {
        throw error(Error::wrongUseOfFunction(funcName()));
    }

    menuAot = _args.parmObject();
    tn = menuAot.getFirstNode();

    dc = new DictClass(className2Id(tn.AOTname()));
    if (!dc)
    {
        throw error(Error::wrongUseOfFunction(funcName()));
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= dc.objectMethodCnt(); i++)
    {
        dm = dc.objectMethodObject(i);
        dmName = dm.name();
        if (dm.isStatic()
            || dm.isDelegate()
            || dm.accessSpecifier() != AccessSpecifier::public
            || dm.name() == identifierStr(classDeclaration)
        )
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!itnRoot)
        {
            itnRoot = TreeNode::findNode(#ClassesPath).AOTadd("I" + dc.name());
            itnRoot.AOTsave();

            itnChild = itnRoot.AOTfirstChild();
            itnChild.AOTsetSource(strFmt('public interface I%1\n{\n}', dc.name()));
        }

        itnChild = itnRoot.AOTadd(dm.name());
        intParams = '';
        for (j = 1; j <= dm.parameterCnt(); j++)
        {
            if (j > 1)
            {
                intParams+= ', ';
            }
            intParams+= strFmt('%1 %2', extendedTypeId2DisplayName(dm.parameterType(j), dm.parameterId(j)), dm.parameterName(j));
        }
        intSrc = strFmt('public %1 %2(%3)\n{\n}', extendedTypeId2DisplayName(dm.returnType(), dm.returnId()), dm.name(), intParams);
        itnChild.AOTsetSource(intSrc);
    }

    if (itnRoot)
    {
        itnRoot.AOTcompile();
        itnRoot.AOTrestore();
        itnRoot.AOTnewWindow();
        itnRoot.AOTedit();
    }
}
```